# Difference between 2 consecutive elements in Prolog

Tags: prolog, turbo-prolog

So my problem sounds like this: Given a list of integer numbers, generate the list of permutations with the property that the absolute value of the difference between 2 consecutive values from the permutation is `<=3`.
For example : `L=[2,7,5]` ==> `[[2,5,7], [7,5,2]]`.

So far I wrote this

```
domains 
list=integer*
lista=list*

predicates
perm(list,list)
permutations(list,lista,integer)
delete(integer,list,list)
diff(list,integer)

clauses
perm([],[]).
perm(Y,[A|X]):-
     delete(A,Y,Y1),
     perm(Y1,X).
delete(A,[A|X],X).
delete(A,[B|X],[B|Y]):-
     delete(A,X,Y).

perm_aux(L,X,3):-
     perm(L,X),
     diff(X,R),
     abs(R)<=3.

diff([],0).
diff(???):-
  ??????

permutations(L,R,3):-
     findall(X,perm_aux(L,X,3),R).
```

So I'm stuck in the part where I make the difference. I have no idea how to do it for every 2 consecutive elements. Please help me.

Comment: I only need to make the difference for consecutive numbers. If I take combinations of pairs I could get a good difference even for numbers that are not consecutive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't have `diff` return a difference, but rather give it the max difference you want and have it either fail as soon as it hits a difference that is too big, or it succeeds.

So `diff(List, Max).` And calling it, instead of:

```
diff(X,R),
abs(R)<=3.  % Note that this should be =<
```

You'd have:

```
diff(X, 3).
```

Then your base cases are:

```
diff([], _).   % Empty list always succeeds
diff([_], _).  % Single element list always succeeds
```

And your recursive case would look like:

```
diff([X,Y|T], Max) :-
    abs(X-Y) =< Max,
    diff([Y|T], Max).
```

If you would like `diff` to provide a maximum absolute difference of consecutive values, you could define it as:

```
max_diff(X, Max) :-
    max_diff(X, 0, Max).
max_diff([], M, M).
max_diff([_], M, M).
max_diff([X,Y|T], MaxSoFar, Max) :-
    Diff is abs(X-Y),
    (   Diff > MaxSoFar
    ->  max_diff([Y|T], Diff, Max)
    ;   max_diff([Y|T], MaxSoFar, Max)
    ).
```

Comment: I have written there abs(Y-X)>Max,!,..... and I'm stuck again. How shoul I call recursively the diff again?

Comment: @user3043278 you want `abs(X-Y) =< Max` since you want to program for success. Think about the recursion... if you just compared `X,Y` in `[X,Y|T]` then what would you want to compare next?

Comment: You're right, but this piece of code also shows me two other lists in which only the first 2 numbers check the difference, the next ones don't